# Joined a domain, no prompt for administrator login when elevated privileges are required

Tags: windows-7, uac, windows-domain

I have added a new computer to Windows domain, but when I try to do something, what requires elevated privileges, I just get a message to contact administrator, but no promt to enter administrator credentials. On other computers the promt is presented, but there's none on this one.

I have access to server and to administrator account.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the local security policies (`secpol.msc`), specifically the "User Account Control: Behavior of the Elevation Prompt for Standard Users" under Local Policies->User Rights Assignment.

You may also want to run an `RSOP.msc` on the system in question to see which, and how the various group policies may be affecting it.